Compilación en Android
GX18u8
Android
JDK17

Da el siguiente error en la compilación y por lo tanto no crea el APK:

Sucede al hacer  Rebuild All y haber borrado la carpeta mobile.
Lo extraño es que generaba sin problemas y comenzó a fallar hoy. Intenté pasarle --offline en Gradle Options pero no tuve suerte sigue igual.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990054/android-studio-resolving-duplicate-classes

Al final fue solucionado actualizando un componente del proyecto a su última version actual:
WWP v15u2.11


El error indica clases duplicadas, debido probablemente por alguna actualización en tu proyecto, probablemente algunas de tus bibliotecas no estan migradas a AndroidX de acuerdo al mensaje de error
Abre tu archivo gradle.properties y revisa que tenga definido lo sigueinte:
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

genera nuevamente tu proyecto.
